# How to decode this seemingly GBK-encoded string?

Tags: email, character-encoding, attachments, chinese, decoding

I have a `.eml` email file containing a MS-Word attachment:

```
------=_Part_239376_662463351.1415605722579
Content-Type: application/msword;
 name="=?GBK?B?1cK5scf4s8e53L7WudjT2s34wufT38fp0MXPoteo?=
 =?GBK?B?sai1xLTwuLQoz8K6vszBMbrFKS5kb2M=?="
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename="=?GBK?B?1cK5scf4s8e53L7WudjT2s34wufT38fp0MXPoteo?=
 =?GBK?B?sai1xLTwuLQoz8K6vszBMbrFKS5kb2M=?="

0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAA [rest of base64-encoded attachment]
```

I successfully base64-decoded the attachment, and the file content is fine.
**But how to decode the file name?**

The value of `filename=""` *seems* to be [GBK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK)-encoded but Python's `.decode('gbk')` does not work on it, same string returned:

```
>>> "1cK5scf4s8e53L7WudjT2s34wufT38fp0MXPoteo".decode('gbk')
u'1cK5scf4s8e53L7WudjT2s34wufT38fp0MXPoteo'
```

So, what is this string encoded in and how to decode it?

```
=?GBK?B?1cK5scf4s8e53L7WudjT2s34wufT38fp0MXPoteo?=
=?GBK?B?sai1xLTwuLQoz8K6vszBMbrFKS5kb2M=?=
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These –

```
=?GBK?B?1cK5scf4s8e53L7WudjT2s34wufT38fp0MXPoteo?=
=?GBK?B?sai1xLTwuLQoz8K6vszBMbrFKS5kb2M=?=
```

– are MIME **[Encoded-Words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word)**. The general form is:

```
=?<Charset>?<TransportEncoding>?<EncodedText>?=
```

You're correct that the charset is GBK, but you must first unwrap the *transport encoding*, which is either `B` for Base64 or `Q` for Quoted-Printable, to get at the actual GBK-encoded bytes:

```pycon
>>> base64.b64decode("sai1xLTwuLQoz8K6vszBMbrFKS5kb2M=").decode("GBK")
'报的答复(下壕塘1号).doc'
```

However, `email.header.decode_header()` will handle this better:

```pycon
>>> x = email.header.decode_header("=?GBK?B?1cK5s<...>brFKS5kb2M=?=")
>>> x
[(b'\xd5\xc2\xb9\xb1<...>\xc11\xba\xc5).doc', 'gbk')]
>>> x[0][0].decode(x[0][1])
'章贡区城管局关于网络舆情信息专报的答复(下壕塘1号).doc'
```

The structure of the first result is such because a single header may have multiple components, i.e. different encodings or mixed raw text and Encoded-Words. The Python module leaves it up to you to join() the results:

```python
def decode_header(enc):
    dec = email.header.decode_header(enc)
    dec = [f[0].decode(f[1] or "us-ascii") for f in dec]
    return "".join(dec)
```

Similarly in Perl, its `Encode::decode()` can also handle this using the `MIME-Header` encoding:

```bash
$ perl -E 'use open qw(:std :utf8);
           use Encode;
           say Encode::decode("MIME-Header", "=?GBK?B?1cK5scf<...>brFKS5kb2M=?=");'
章贡区城管局关于网络舆情信息专报的答复(下壕塘1号).doc
```

(Also, the body isn't uuencoded, it's **Base64**-encoded. They use different character sets, even though both are 3:4 encodings and `uudecode` is usually smart enough to detect raw Base64.)

Comment: Thanks for the uu/base64 note, I fixed my question, thanks!